# How do I use tensorflow magenta to produce new songs?

Tags: tensorflow, magenta

I've followed the instructions at:

https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta

and run the following command line.

```
./bazel-bin/magenta/convert_midi_dir_to_note_sequences --output_file=../output --midi-dir=../midi
```

My machine chugs for a couple of minutes and produces a fairly massive output file, which is cool.

My question is, what do I need to do next to generate a new composition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've recently added a model that you can train to generate new sequences. Have a look at https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/blob/master/magenta/models/basic_rnn/README.md.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The goal in that step is to create a `notesequences.tfrecord`. Your commands should have been:

```
MIDI_DIRECTORY=../midi  
SEQUENCES_TFRECORD=../notesequences.tfrecord  

bazel run //magenta/scripts:convert_midi_dir_to_note_sequences -- \  
--midi_dir=$MIDI_DIRECTORY \  
--output_file=$SEQUENCES_TFRECORD \  
--recursive
```

Then proceed to creating a data set, training and generating midi songs.